# How to set global PATH on OS X Server 10.6.6?

Tags: web-server, tomcat, mac-osx-server, path

I'm running Tomcat on OS X Server 10.6.6 under the normal Web component that comes with the OS. This has worked fine so far, but I need to add some entries to the `$PATH` environment variable for programs that I want access to from the web server (more specifically, I'm running Hudson under Tomcat which needs access to build tools that I have installed).

Tomcat and the Web component seems to run under the user __appserver_ which has a different `$PATH` than the administrator account.

What's the proper way to add a global entry to the `$PATH` in OS X Server for the Web component? Preferable it should be done only once so that both the __appserver_ and *Administrator* user can access the same `$PATH`.

**EDIT:** Adding the path to `/etc/paths` or `/etc/paths.d/somefile` didn't work. Tomcat and Hudson does still not see those directories.

Answer (score 1):

You can set global paths in MacOS X by adding a file to `/etc/paths.d` with the path you wish to add.

This change will affect all the users on your system, so it covers exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I added a simple project in Hudson to see which paths it had. It only showed the path `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` even though there are many more added in `/etc/paths.d` for example. They show up for normal users but not Hudson.